# Reading qr code with java me

Tags: netbeans, java-me, qr-code

I need to develop a mobile app that runs java (java me). This application needs to open the camera and read the qrcode. Does anyone know if you have any library to develop it? I'm using netbeans, researched enough on the internet and found nothing.

Comment: You of course already tried Googling and thus found this, right? http://qrcode.osdn.jp/index.html.en